# Seperate Django Rest framework app and Angularjs app , how do they communicate?

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I'm new to AngularJs and I'm trying to make an AngularJS application that consumes JSON from a Django Rest framework api , and I have been advised to seperate the project into 2 seperate apps one for Django and an othet for AngularJS (even using 2 different IDEs) , my question is how can I set up my AngularJS app and my Django app so they can communicate with each other knowing that I'm working on localhost ?
How will Django Rest framework respond to the AngularJS requests ? 
Thank you

Comment: You want to run 2 applications on the same port/url or you want to separate them?

Comment: I would like for AngularJs to run on the client side and Django on the server side , however didn't exactly figure out what type of configuration I need in order for them to communicate . 
I set up CORS in Rest Framework and still looking what to do from Angular's side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to have a Django template view serving your client (AngularJS) application.
Another would be to use NodeJS + Express + Grunt/Gulp to serve the client application on another port on localhost and set up [CORS](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/) in Rest Framework.
Either way you'll then do `$http.get/post/whatever` calls to the Django `host:port` app from the client application.

I usually use the second approach.

**views.py**

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

**urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = patterns('public.views',
    url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
```

**templates/home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load i18n %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load compress %}

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    ...

    {% compress css %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" %}">
        ...
    {% endcompress %}
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp">
    ...

    {% compress js %}
    <script src="{% static "libs/jquery/jquery.js" %}"></script>
    ...
    <script src="{% static "js/my-app/controllers/my-controller.js" %}"></script>
    ....
    {% endcompress %}
</body>
```

For the AngularJS part I use [Gulp, Browserify and a lot of other stuff](https://bitbucket.org/sergiuparaschiv/angularjs-boilerplate). Please take that boilerplate with a grain of salt, I came up with that for a very specific set of reasons.

Comment: I concur with the second approach if one has the freedom to choose. Note that CORS is unnecessary if both of the AngularJS ap and the Django app are being served from the same host (of course, different ports).